# Sample usage of gatsby-plugin-recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha, gatsby

I have to use gatsby-plugin-recaptcha for forms in my project. I am not able to find any example of usage of this plugin. It will be big help if someone can share any information regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Place this code in your component
and import `<Helmet/>` from react-helmet.

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Helmet>
    <script src={`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?r=${Math.random()}`} async defer>
    </script>
  </Helmet>
  <form>
    <div className="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey={REACAPTCHA_PUBLIC}>
    </div>
  </form>
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: This may not be a perfect answer to the question asked - But I'm up-voting this, as this was the correct solution to site which I took over. The standard captcha implementation works fine, until you navigate to another page, also with a captcha field.

This random number being appended, solves the problem, even if it is a hack

Comment: The question is to specifically use the gatsby-plugin-recaptcha here you are using the script from google.

Answer (score 0):

` --> npm install --save reaptcha

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Reaptcha from 'reaptcha';

class MyForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  verified: false
 };
}

const onVerify = (recaptchaResponse) => {
this.setState({
  verified: true
});
};
```

render() {
    return (
      
        
        
          Submit
        
      
       );
     }
    }

```
 see the reference: https://github.com/sarneeh/reaptcha`
```